What is the the correct plumbing rough in for washer/dryer, water heater, and AC drain line in one location?
My condominium was built in the late 80's. I'm curious if this can be designed in a better way.
Starting with our air handler, both the main drain (light green) and backup pan drain (dark green) T into the same connection which drops down a 3/4 pvc into an "air gap?" Ideally I would run two dedicated AC drain lines off our third story unit (not allowed). I believe the air gap is there for the hot water heaters pressure relief valve pvc pipe.
I could easily eliminate the air gap cup thing and just run the ac drain line through the top of the washer box. I could pipe in the 3/4 pressure relief pipe through the studs and down into the washer box as well to clean things up as well.
I would like to know what the correct way would be to go about this while I have everything open.



No sorry - you need an air gap for BOTH the HVAC drain lines and water heater pressure relief lines. This is to prevent cross contamination of sewage to the HVAC and potable water systems. I don't see how you could stuff all those drains into the laundry box because the washing machine drain hose would mostly fill the drain. Note the output from a water heater pressure relief line can be quite vigorous so I would make sure it is centered over that cup drain.

I've read what you've said several times and I am a bit confused. Am I supposed to have a second air gap for the water heater pressure relief? Like an additional T over to an additional air gap cup?

No you can put both drain lines tied together over the drain cup. Do not T them together.

Thank you for the clarification!
